# how to Store messages at client side when server goes down using wcf?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I came across a situation in my work environment. where i have wcf service which receives messages from client and store in db. Now my problem is suppose server was down for 10 mins these 10 mins messages should be stored in client at some place and client should check for availability of server for every 1 min.Is there any procedure that i could follow or any help would be appreciated .Thank you

```
binding :netTCPBinding
```

Comment: Simple, switch to MSMQ binding, assuming of course this is a LAN envionment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSMQ does exactly what your first sentence says - when you send an MSMQ message, if it can't get the remote queue then it stays with the client and the built-in MSMQ service retries in the background. That way your message, once sent, is "safe." It's going to reach its destination if at all possible. (If you have a massive message volume and messages need to be stored for a long time then storage capacity can be an issue, but that's very, very unlikely.)

#### Configure WCF to send/receive MSMQ messages

I'd only do this if it's necessary. It involves modifying both the service and the client, and the documentation isn't too friendly.

[Here's the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008(v=vs.110).aspx) for MsmqBinding. Steps 3 and 4 for configuring the WCF service are blank. That's not helpful! When I selected the .NET 4.0 documentation those details are filled in.

I looked at several tutorials, and if I was going to look at this I'd start with [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34168/WCF-Queued-Messaging). I find that a lot of tutorials muddy concepts by explaining too many things at once and including unnecessary information about other parts of the writers' projects.

#### The client queues its messages locally

If you don't to make lots of modifications to your service to support MsmqBinding. You could just implement the queuing locally. If the WCF service is down, the client puts the message in a local MSMQ queue and then at intervals reads the messages back from that queue and tries sending to the WCF service again. (If the WCF service is still down, put the message back in the queue.)

I'd just send messages straight to the queue and have another process dequeue and send to WCF. That way the client itself just "fires and forgets" if that's okay.

That way you don't have to deal with the hassle of modifying your service, but you still get the benefit. If your message can't go to the WCF service then it goes someplace "safe" where it can even survive the client app terminating or the computer restarting.

Sending and receiving messages in a local queue is much easier to configure. Your client can check to see if the queues exist and [create them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yka0xsf(v=vs.110).aspx) if needed. This is much easier to work with and the code samples are much more complete and on-point.

Comment: Can't i do the same with netTcpBinding instaed of MSMQ because binding is supposed to be netTcp

Comment: No, the two bindings are completely different. It sounds like these are one-way messages because the client isn't failing when the message isn't sent. So based on that I'd skip the hassle of changing your bindings (why risk breaking stuff) and just use a local message queue. The way your client talks to your server won't change. It will just have a reliable way to retry messages if the WCF server isn't available.